# D3.js updating bar chat

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var barData = [10, 35, 8, 50, 25];

var chartWeight = 800,
    chartHeight = 400,
    barWidth = 50,
    barOffset = 5;

var myChart = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: chartWeight,
        height: chartHeight
    })
    .style({
        background: '#C9D7D6'
    });

function draw(data) {

    var bars = myChart.selectAll('rect').data(data);

    bars.exit().remove();

    bars.enter().append('rect')
        .attr({
            x: function (d, i) {
                return (barWidth+barOffset)*i;
            },
            y: function (d) {
                return chartHeight-d;
            },
            width: barWidth,
            height: function (d) {
                return d;
            }
        })
        .style({
            fill: '#C61C6F'
        });

}

draw(barData);

setTimeout(function () {
    var newData = [30, 25, 55];
    draw(newData);
}, 2000);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gwsuorMUVHDtZzOZnp8Y?p=preview

I am trying to update the bar chat with new array of values. The number got updated according to the new array but the size of bars did not change. can someone spot my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an "update" selection:

```
bars.attr({
        x: function (d, i) {
            return (barWidth+barOffset)*i;
        },
        y: function (d) {
            return chartHeight-d;
        },
        width: barWidth,
        height: function (d) {
            return d;
        }
    });
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqmdyw6k/

Answer (score 0):

Separate the rects that are configured once and updated.

```
var barData = [10, 35, 8, 50, 25];

var chartWeight = 800,
    chartHeight = 400,
    barWidth = 50,
    barOffset = 5;

var myChart = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: chartWeight,
        height: chartHeight
    })
    .style({
        background: '#C9D7D6'
    });

function draw(data) {

    var bars = myChart.selectAll('rect').data(data);

    bars.enter().append('rect')
        .attr({
            x: function (d, i) {
                return (barWidth+barOffset)*i;
            },
            width: barWidth
        });

    // the height (y) is updated 
    bars.attr({y: function (d) {
            return chartHeight-d;
        },
        height: function (d) {
         return d;
        }})
        .style({
        　fill: '#C61C6F'
      　});

    bars.exit().remove();
}

draw(barData);

setTimeout(function () {
    var newData = [30, 25, 55];
    draw(newData);
}, 2000);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TbTjSFeBfSfyRTaZZlAQ?p=preview